# Can a discord bot go back and react to all old messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord, discord.js

This vould be for an image voting system. Im thinking about:
After 10 sec my bot denies the message sending ability to @everyone, but at the same time puts a reaction to all the messages, that have been sent in, so people can vote for each and every image. (ADD_REACTIONS is off all the time)

```
setTimeout(() => {
      var channel = client.channels.cache.get(`823225045231992892`) 
      
        channel.send('You cant send more messages, but you can vote now!');
        channel.overwritePermissions(
          [
            {
              id: channel.guild.id,
              allow: ["SEND_MESSAGES"],
            },
          ],
          "Deny access to send messages"
        );
    }, 0);
```

Comment: before send messages is dey, and at the end 0 is actually 10000 i know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess This is what you wanted to do

```js
//Guessing the channel is catched as Channel
Channel.send("The reactable message").then(msg => {
    msg.react("100000000001").then( () => { //Put the available Emoji ID
        setTimeout( () => {
            msg.reactions.cache.get("100000000001").remove().cache(console.log);
            msg.react("❌"); //the unavailable Emoji
        },1000);
    })
});
```